# Родственны ли слова "губы" и "губить"?

Tags: этимология, недопустимая-метка

Слова "губы" и "губить" одного корня или просто похоже звучат?

Comment: ср.
И свои-то мне губы не любы —
И убийство на том же корню —
https://rvb.ru/mandelstam/01text/vol_3/01versus/01versus/3_179.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У слова "губа" несколько значений. Одно из них - судебный округ (устаревшее), действительно может быть связано с "губить".

Остальные значения (рот, гриб, морской залив, гауптвахта) не родственны предыдущему. Первые два, видимо, связаны и восходят к индоевропейской основе с общим значением "гнуть".

Answer (score 2):

Цыганенко Г.П. (Этимологический словарь русского языка) подтверждает, что эти слова имеют общее происхождение.
Общеслав. праслав. *gubiti 'губить' является глаголом с тем же корнем* gub- 'гнуть', что и в слове *гибнуть*. 
Собств. губить — 'заставлять гнуться, сгибаться, гибнуть', 'приводить к 
гибели, потере'. Оно образовано с помощью суффикса -и-ти от *губа* 'изгиб', 'гибель, 
пагуба' (XIV—XV вв.).